# when i using appium on findElement method,i have element instance,but the element didn't get focus

Tags: automation, appium, android-tv, appium-android, android-uiautomator

is the Custom android tv,it can use element instance click() method.

when i using findElement method,it can get element instance,but not focus the element

how can i set the element on focus?

thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a minimal reproducable example (see stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for images, links, etc:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

for input box and etc:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: What type of element you are trying to focus on? Like an image, textbox etc...

Comment: imageView,textView..etc.

Comment: it looks like selneium api,maybe it works for pc web,but my devices is a carry Touch function android tv,calling element click() method can work,but sometimes i just want to focus the element,not click in it,just like you press keycode to move the focus on it